# How to release a viewcontroller while using addSubview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I've the code as below:

```
+(void) addHeader:(UIViewController*) hostViewController requiresBackBtn:(BOOL)BooleanValue
{       
    ApplicationHeader *appHeader = [[ApplicationHeader alloc] initWithNibName:@"ApplicationHeader" bundle:nil];
    appHeader.hostViewController = hostViewController;
    [appHeader.view setFrame:CGRectZero];
    [hostViewController.view addSubview:appHeader.view];

    if (BooleanValue) {
        [appHeader.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 97)];
    }
    else {
        [appHeader.backBtn setHidden:TRUE]; 
        [appHeader.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 74)];
    }
//    [appHeader release]; // This call tends to app Crash!!!!!
}
```

If I call release to appHeader then the app crashes I press the button which found in appHeader!!
And if I doesn't this is a memory leak.

What to do now?
:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what an ApplicationHeader is, but I know that yours has a retained view from 
`[hostViewController.view addSubview:appHeader.view];`
Would ApplicationHeader be better as a subclass of `UIView`? Without more information, I'm not sure what to suggest as a solution but I think you need to rethink what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Actually the ApplicationHeader is a view controller, which is a common view controller that has 3 buttons which are common throughout applications.

I hope now you have a better idea

Comment: not really. never heard of it and I can't find any information on it... course I pretty much exclusively develop for the iphone and it sounds like a design already provided by cocoa-touch. In any case, the other answer has a good point. If ApplicationHeader is a viewcontroller, it should be singularly responsible for its view.

Answer (score 0):

Adding other controller's view in your viewController is against Apple's "one controller per screen" policy. It will surely give level 1 and 2 memory warnings and app will crash intempestively.